# Recompute big table in SQL database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

We are fighting this problem:

- We have a big table in `SQL Server 2008 R2` (R2 !) (millions of rows)
- We need to walk through this table and each row needs to be recomputed by a `C#` code (so the table is loaded from `C#` application)

How to do that if performance is crucial? Some kind of batching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is crucial, use SQL CLR to compute the new values. You can just use an update statement that way. SQL CLR places restrictions on what code you can use so this might not be an easy option.

There is another way if SQL CLR is not an option:

I assume there is an integer primary key. I'd do it like this:

- request a batch of rows (10k or so)
- compute the updates
- send the updates
- repeat

The trick is to keep track of which rows you already processed. Keep the ID value of the last row processed. Request a batch like this:

```
select top 10000 *
from T
where ID > @lastIDProcessed
order by ID
```

That will guarantee fast an reliable execution.

Comment: Please, CLR sounds interesting. Could you write a small snippet? But our C# code is very complex.

Comment: Yeah it is not really possible to post a small snippet with SQL CLR ;-) If your code is complex I recommend the latter option.

Comment: Right. Send them using table values parameters into a procedure or inline SQL command. Don't issue 10k individual updates. Issue them in one statement using the TVP as input.